# Pylance incorrectly typing numpy.pi as "Module("numpy.testing") | Type[NoseTester]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pylance

I was adding type hints to a function call when I noticed that Pylance is typing `numpy.pi` as a member of `numpy.testing` or being of type NoseTester.

Even though I get `type(np.pi) == float` in the python command line, this sample code:

```py
import numpy as np

def foo(val: float):
    print(val)

foo(np.pi)
```

Gives the following error message on `foo(np.pi)`

```
pi: Module("numpy.testing") | Type[NoseTester]
Argument of type "Module("numpy.testing") | Type[NoseTester]" cannot be assigned to parameter "val" of type "float" in function "foo"
  Type "Module("numpy.testing") | Type[NoseTester]" cannot be assigned to type "float"
    Type "Module("numpy.testing")" cannot be assigned to type "float"
    "Type[type]" is incompatible with "Type[float]"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

I have gotten the same error message (for types other than float) for the following things: `numpy.pi`, `numpy.e`, `numpy.floor`, `numpy.ceil`, `numpy.sin`, `numpy.cos`, `numpy.tan`, `numpy.sqrt`, `numpy.exp`.

However, these floats/functions don't result in the issue: `numpy.Inf`, `numpy.Nan`, `numpy.round`, `numpy.real`, `numpy.imag`, `numpy.random.rand`.

I'm Running:

- Numpy: 1.19.5
- Pylance: 2021.5.3

Does anyone know why this is and/or how to fix the issue?

**Edit 1**: This seems like it might be more of a Pylance issue, so I've created [microsoft/pylance-release#1340](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1340)

Comment: Really weird. I can't reproduce using normal python, but of course this is VS, so who knows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel really dumb--I just had to update Numpy to version 1.20. As was pointed out [on GitHub by Jake Bailey](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1340#issuecomment-847305413), Numpy did not include typing information prior to 1.20.